# Получение charset

Tags: php

Как при помощи PHP можно получить charset из

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />

$get = file_get_contents('http://test1.ru/);
preg_match_all("/<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=(.*?)" />/",$get,$matches);
$p = $matches[1][0];
echo $p;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мои экстрасенсорные способности подсказывают мне, что у вас ошибка в синтаксисе и ваш скрипт вообще не запускается. Странно что это подсказывают мне именно экстрасенсорные способности а не вы.

Код:

```
$get = file_get_contents('http://test1.ru/);

preg_match_all('/<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text\/html; charset=(.*?)" \/>/',$get,$matches);
$p = $matches[1][0];
echo $p;
```

И пожалуйста (вам это кстати будет полезно) почитайте про экранирование символов и вам всё сразу станет ясно.

P.S.
Для того чтобы не париться с экранированием символов в регулярных выражениях, используйте для указания границ регулярки символы, которые не используются внутри самой регулярки. То есть в вашем случае это мог бы быть символ **#** например.

```
#<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=(.*?)" />#
```

В таком случае можно не задумываться над экранированием слешей. Вот.

Comment: А вот это почему то не получает <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: Решил, можно закрывать